# python error when extracting a rar file: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Tags: python, spyder, data-extraction, rar, winrar

I am using [rarfile](https://pypi.org/project/rarfile/) to extract code in Spyder(python3.6). When trying to execute the following code

```
import rarfile
rar_file = "d:\\test\\reza3.rar"
rar_file = rarfile.RarFile(rar_file)
rar_file.extractall(pwd='123')
```

I am receiving this error

```py
    In [25]: rar_file = "d:\\test\\reza3.rar"
    
    In [26]: rar_file = rarfile.RarFile(rar_file)
    
    In [27]: rar_file.extractall(pwd='321')
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    
      File "<ipython-input-27-61fee530b204>", line 1, in <module>
        rar_file.extractall(pwd='321')
    
      File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\rarfile.py", line 847, in extractall
        dst = self._extract_one(inf, path, pwd, not inf.is_dir())
    
      File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\rarfile.py", line 912, in _extract_one
        return self._make_file(info, dstfn, pwd, set_attrs)
    
      File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\rarfile.py", line 925, in _make_file
        with self.open(info, "r", pwd) as src:
    
      File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\rarfile.py", line 783, in open
        return self._file_parser.open(inf, pwd)
    
      File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\rarfile.py", line 1241, in open
        return self._open_unrar(self._rarfile, inf, pwd)
    
      File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\rarfile.py", line 1294, in _open_unrar
        cmd = setup.open_cmdline(pwd, rarfile, fn)
    
      File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\rarfile.py", line 3235, in open_cmdline
        cmdline = self.get_cmdline("open_cmd", pwd)
    
      File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\rarfile.py", line 3247, in get_cmdline
        self.add_password_arg(cmdline, pwd)
    
      File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\rarfile.py", line 3265, in add_password_arg
        cmdline.extend(args)
    
    TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

What is causing the `TypeError`? Any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You could start by including the full error trace in the question so we can see how the error occurred.

Comment: Its not able to find the `rar` file probably. Try using `os.path` to access the file instead of passing in a string like that.

Comment: This is not as simple as it first seems.  If `rar_file` were `None`, the last line would produce the error `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'extractall'`, not an error about not being iterable.  Where is this iteration occuring is the question?  @VidaHarati, you really should add the full stack trace of the error to your question, and provide us with more code if there is more.

Comment: Bizarre.  This has something to do with the password for the file. I don't see what you could do differently.  Even if both your file and your password were bad, you shouldn't get an error like this.  Seems like a bug, but I don't know how that can be, as I'm sure this is well-tested territory.

Comment: the code works for the files without password, but for password protected archives, it gave the same error!!!

Answer (score 0):

Use "with" ,try this, place at the same directory

```
from rarfile import RarFile
with RarFile('reza3.rar', 'r') as extr:
     extr.extractall(pwd='<your_password>')
```

Comment: from rarfile import RarFile
with RarFile('D:\\test\\reza3.rar', 'r') as extr:
     extr.extractall(pwd='123')         but the same error